# How do we know that somebody already rates the app before redirecting him/her to Google play?

Tags: android, google-play

Form inside my application, I want to give a pop up for user to rate my app. Now I have implemented a dialogue box which is prompted every third time user launches the app and asks the user to rate the app. It has two buttons - "rate me" and "No, thanks". If user clicks "rate me", it redirects to my app in Google play to allow the user to rate the app.

Now my question is how can I find inside my application if user has rated my app. He may go to Google play but do not rate it. What is the best design. Should I stop showing the dialogue once user is redirected to my app in Google Play?

Comment: Such App behaviour would be a reason for me to give it a 1 star rating.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for app to know is user rated or not. Just redirect user to google play and after that stop displaying that dialog.