# How to avoid redirecting to play store users which already rated app?

Tags: android, google-play

The app has to ask for rating and opinion which will be tried internally and if some criteria are met, the user should be redirected to play store.

But I don't want to redirect user which already put any comment for current version of app. So I want to avoid unnecessary redirection.

Is a way pass rating request to Play Store or some Google's service and this service will decide without passing any info to the app?

**I don't want to know if user rate the app or what value this rate has. I'm looking a Google service/API which on Google side make decision for me. I just fire & forget.**

So below similar questions are not responcing on my question:

- [How do we know that somebody already rates the app before redirecting him/her to Google play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459209/how-do-we-know-that-somebody-already-rates-the-app-before-redirecting-him-her-to)
- [How to know if a specific user has rated a Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318700/how-to-know-if-a-specific-user-has-rated-a-android-app)
- [How to find out from with application, if rating for app is already done by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185348/how-to-find-out-from-with-application-if-rating-for-app-is-already-done-by-user)
- [How to know if a specific user has rated a Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318700/how-to-know-if-a-specific-user-has-rated-a-android-app)

but I don't want that app get any info about users.

Comment: You've posted 3 links, all of which have the exact same answer you'll get here.

Comment: @TheWanderer see updated question

Comment: The api you're looking for does not exist. The answers in the linked question are still the best option